# Processing time increases with the number of Threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pymeshlab

I'm working with the `pymeshlab` library. I noticed a weird behavior with `multithreading` while using one of their filters `generate_surface_reconstruction_screened_poisson` which can be found here: https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#generate_surface_reconstruction_screened_poisson

What it basically does is, create a watertight surface from oriented point sets. For example, if there are holes or missing surfaces in your mesh, it will reconstruct the surface of that area using the adjacent point sets as a reference.

The left is the input and the right is the output:

[image]

For this filter, there is an argument `threads` that can be passed which essentially represents

```
threads : int = 16 (default)

Number Threads: Maximum number of threads that the reconstruction algorithm can use.
```

Now I have tried with different numbers of threads but it seems like the best performance in terms of execution time I'm getting while setting the number of threads to two. Increasing or decreasing the number of threads just increases the time elapsed in the execution of the filter.
Here's my implementation:

```
import pymeshlab
import time

for thread_number in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]:
    ms = pymeshlab.MeshSet()
    ms.load_new_mesh('FullHead.obj')

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    ms.apply_filter('generate_surface_reconstruction_screened_poisson', visiblelayer=True, preclean=True, threads=thread_number)
    elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
    print(f"time taken for running with {thread_number} threads: {elapsed_time} seconds\n")
    
    ms.save_current_mesh(f'recons_output/{thread_number}_reconstructed_mesh.obj')
```

Output:

```
time taken for running with 1 threads: 7.891609824000625 seconds

time taken for running with 2 threads: 7.006016070998157 seconds

time taken for running with 4 threads: 10.419608506999793 seconds

time taken for running with 8 threads: 17.781056181996973 seconds

time taken for running with 16 threads: 31.617957017999288 seconds
```

This behavior seems quite strange to me. The number of cores and available threads in my CPU is 4. Here's my CPU specs: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/97456/intel-core-i57300hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz/specifications.html

Shouldn't increasing the number of threads make the execution faster for at least the number of threads set to four? Also, let me know if there is any other way to achieve faster execution for surface reconstruction with the screened-poisson algorithm.

P.S. If you want to try in your system, here's the `FullHead.obj` file uploaded in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XjRq1HFyXvogDTSQtiKD2raIgvof5Tkj/view?usp=drive_link

You can find similar results on google-colab too: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1D-44yptui8tVCGU286y6Pi09yi0r4-Ce?usp=sharing

Comment: multithreading in python doesn't use multiple cpu cores because of the GIL so I would suspect that the time gains are simply from the overhead of spinning off new threads

Comment: yeah, I know it doesn't use multiple cores, I meant as in using one thread per core. anyway, yeah you might be right that the overhead of spinning new threads might be increasing time, still by how much the time is increasing seems a bit suspicious. Another thing is I'm getting slightly better performance with 2 threads instead of one

Comment: Just installed pymeshlab on windows 11, and tested your script right now. It gave me different results from what you expected. Here's the output: 1 thread: ~6.2s; 2 threads: ~4.7s; 4 threads ~3.3s; 8 threads ~2.7s; 16 threads ~4.3s; My notebook specifications: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 2.80 GHz, 16,0 GB RAM, Win 11 x64 ver 22H2, python version is 3.10.2, pymeshlab 2023.12.post1. What are your specs? Are you using the last version of pymeshlab? Does your hardware gives you multiple cores and threads?

Comment: yeah, I'm using the latest version of `pymeshlab`. My notebook specifications: 7th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ 3.50 GHz, 16,0 GB RAM, POP-OS 22.04, python version is 3.10.12, pymeshlab 2023.12. And my CPU has 4 cores, yes it gives me multiple cores and threads

Comment: @CarlHR you can find similar results here too: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1D-44yptui8tVCGU286y6Pi09yi0r4-Ce?usp=sharing

Comment: @CarlHR I am expecting the results that you are getting. Setting up the threads numbers similar to your available CPU threads should generate the most optimal performance like what you have,  Unfortunately, that's not what I'm getting. My CPU has 4 cores and 4 threads so I should get the most optimal performance with 4 threads. Here's my CPU specs: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/97456/intel-core-i57300hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: That's just an assumption but, based on your specs and mine, what differs is the cpu. Mine is an i7 and yours is an i5. Based on the intel specifications, my cpu supports hyper-threading, which grants execution of 2 threads per physical core. I've also seen a few posts on the pymeshlab github issue pages, where some random person a few years ago asked the author to release the GIL inside the scripts. The post was closed, so the author probably did fix it. Maybe its a hardware problem after all.

Comment: On the link you provided, `os.cpu_count()` results in 2. When I execute this on my system, it resusts in 8. That's probably the cap of performance on our systems.

Comment: the link is to a colab-notebook, not my system, mind you. I'm saying that's also odd